# How to run a subset of the unit tests with Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xcode4, ocunit

Xcode 4 introduces the scheme feature. With which you can create different schemes for your project. Under the test item in a scheme you can select which tests to run. However, I'm finding that all the tests are run, not just the ones I'm selecting. How can I just run a subset of my unit tests?

I suspect my problem is related to the fact that my project and unit tests were originally created with Xcode 3 and imported into Xcode 4.

There was an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352971/how-do-i-run-a-subset-of-ocunit-tests-in-xcode) about this sort of problem, but my question is specifically about Xcode 4.0.2.

Comment: What are you doing to run the tests? Product -> Test? or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Product -> Test command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in a post 4.0 release of Xcode. I'm using 4.5 and it is fixed this release, but I don't know the exact release it was fixed in.